# Scala - Define type for Either for compactness or write it explicitly for readability?

Tags: scala, api-design, either

In Scala, I can have:

```
trait Api {
    def someApiCall: Either[Failure, GoodResult];
}
```

or

```
object SomeObject {
    type SomeResult = Either[Failure, GoodResult]
}

trait Api {
    def someApiCall: SomeObject.SomeResult;
}
```

where the former is more explicit about the result type and thus easier to read, but involves retyping Either[...] over and over in different implementations. This is solved in in the latter, but then the reader can't conclude much about the result at first sight.

If the return type were `Option` instead of `Either`, I would naturally stick with the former version. For more complex types with many type parameters, the second would be more beneficial. `Either` is somewhere midfield.

My gut feeling is that on the long run the latter is more maintainable. What do you think? Is there a practice regarding this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do one of

1. Declare it explicitly as an `Either[X, Y]`.
2. Declare it as `MaybeResult[Y]` (for `type MaybeResult[A] = Either[Failure, A]`)

Frankly, even then I would declare it explicitly. The advantage of #2 (over your suggestion) is that, with a standard `Failure` type (perhaps `Exception` or `List[String]`), you do *not* have to declare separate type aliases for everywhere you want to use this.

The advantage to using `Either` is that it is **100% clear** for an API user what is happening. However, I would go one step further and use Scalaz's `Validation`:

```
def someApiCall : ValidationNEL[String, Result]
```

The advantage here is that `Validation` is composable in ways that Either is not (otherwise they are *isomorphic* types). For example:

```
def a(i : Int) : ValidationNEL[String, Float]
def b(f : Float) : ValidationNEL[String, Boolean]
```

Then you can compose:

```
a(1) >>= b //ValidationNEL[String, Boolean]
```

Like so:

```
scala>  def a(i : Int) : ValidationNEL[String, Float] = error("")
a: (i: Int)scalaz.Scalaz.ValidationNEL[String,Float]

scala> def b(f : Float) : ValidationNEL[String, Boolean] = error("")
b: (f: Float)scalaz.Scalaz.ValidationNEL[String,Boolean]

scala> lazy val c = a(1) >>= b
c: scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[String],Boolean] = <lazy>
```